# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find radius of convergence of power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{n^2}$ where $a_0=1, a_n=3^{-n}a_{n-1}$ for n $ \in $N.

I tried to get expression for $ a_n $ first which comes to be $ a_n$ =$3^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}.$
Now to find radius of convergence of 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{-\frac{n (n+1)}{2}}z^{n^2}$, I applied root test on it.

So I get $\lim_{n\to \infty}|z|^n 3^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}$= $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{z}{\sqrt{3}})^n$. This thing should be less than 1, to find z. But what to do with this limit?

Comment: For $z=1$ can you compute the limit? what about $z=\sqrt{3}$ and $z=3$?

Comment: For z=1 it can be computed but not for other two

Comment: For any positive number (note that you forgot the absolute value in your limit), you have that $lim a^n$ is either 0 (for $a<1$) , 1 (for $a=1$) and infinity (for $a>1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio test is probably easiest here.
$$ \left|\dfrac{a_n z^{n^2}}{a_{n-1} z^{(n-1)^2}}\right| = 3^{-n} |z|^{2n-1}$$
which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ if $|z|^2 < 3$ and $\infty$ if $|z|^2 > 3$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for the ratio test. No need to solve the recursion. Let
$$
\kappa = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n z^{n^2}|}{|a_{n-1}z^{(n-1)^2}|}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} 3^{-n} |z|^{2n-1} =
\begin{cases} 0, & |z|^2 < 3 \\ \infty, & |z|^2 > 3.  \end{cases}
$$
Hence, the series converges for $|z| < \sqrt{3}$.

(For $|z|=\sqrt{3}$, $\kappa = 1/\sqrt3$, but this is not necessary to get the radius of convergence.)

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} 3^{-n} |z|^{2n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|z|^{2n-1}}{ \sqrt{3}^{2n-1}\sqrt{3}} $  then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|z|^{2n-1}}{ \sqrt{3}^{2n-1}}=0$  if $|z| <\sqrt{3}$. Am I done correct? please help me with the intermediate steps.@mrf

Answer (score 1):

$a_1=\frac{1}{3}$

$a_2=\frac{1}{3^3}$

$a_3=\frac{1}{3^6}$ and so on

So the general term becomes $a_n=\frac{1}{3^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}$
To find radius of convergence note that the series is $a_nz^{n^2}$

Thus the general term is $b_n=a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{3^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}$

Applying ratio test $R=\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}=\sqrt3$

Comment: But  answer is root3

Comment: @User786 please check if this suits you, I have edited my answer.